# How to retain smooth curves in Medibang Paint Pro?

Tags: drawing, line-art

Medibang is the program that I use for drawing the most. So there is a problem that got me worried.

When I draw curves, Medibang somehow coverts it into straight lines, with no tools on.

I tried messing around with tools and stuff, but nothing worked.

[image]

In this picture, I tried drawing a quick circle, this is what came out.

Comment: My first thought is that it could be some extreme lagging because your computer can't handle it. Looking at the title bar interface it might not be so far fetched? I don't use Medibang Paint so that's just my best guess. I don't know if there's like a forum for medibang or something where you could find more people who use the application.

Comment: Like I mentioned before, this looks like an issue with the application and/or computer, but I thought I might as well mention that there are applications for making smooth smooth lineart. These applications don't fix any lag issues, they just help you draw smooth lines accurately. This lazy nezumi introduction video explains the main feature pretty well within the first 20 seconds: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3Hc1bexva70 — Both of these should work in just about any drawing app. Windows: [Lazy nezumi](https://lazynezumi.com/). Mac: [HejStylus](https://hejstylus.com/).

Answer (score 1):

The `Correction` drop-down menu in the properties bar at the top can help you. It will smooth out your curves.
The higher the correction factor, the higher it will correct your curve.

> Note: The higher the correction factor, the higher your CPU will be consumed in processing your curve. Also, that will yield some amount of lag in rendering the curve after you draw it. 
> `Correction: 5 to 10` is ideal imo